# Error on call to shmat

Tags: c++, shared-memory

Try to do something with shared memory by turning a chunk of user buffer into a shared memory, but the shmat() keep failing.

```
# ./a.out
shmid=89260087 0x7fbab055c000
shmat failed: : Invalid argument
```

Here is the source code.   Wonder what's the reason.  Thanks.

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <malloc.h>

char *output;
int n;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    void *p = NULL;
    int i;
    double startTS;
    double tmp;
    output = (char*) valloc(0x1000000);
    sprintf(output, "hi you!!");
    unsigned int size = 0x1000000;
    int shmid = shmget(12348, 0x1000000, IPC_CREAT); //SHM_RDONLY);
    printf("shmid=%d %p\n", shmid, &output[0]);
    char *bigBuf = (char*)shmat(shmid, &output[0], 0);
    if (bigBuf == (void*)-1) {
        perror("shmat failed: "); exit(-1);
    }
    bigBuf[0] = 'x';
    printf("%p enter:\n", bigBuf);
    scanf("%d\n", &i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to attach at an already mapped address. That can't work.

Comment: Thanks @mat, Is there a way to turn a private memory buffer of a process into a shared memory (assume the buffer is page aligned)?

Comment: lol how can that work. take a course on Operating Systems and pay special attention to the virtual memory part

Comment: I thought that In theory, OS can mark the the physical pages for the private memory to be shared.   Sounds it's too naive?